# Should I be worried about rat bite

Tags: infectious-diseases

There is a wild mice that usually enters the house from somewhere and gnaws the skin from foot. It usually gnaws when we are sleeping. It is not a pet rat. It's a wild one. Is there any disease that can be caused by this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. There are a number of diseases that can be transmitted by rodents, and several of them can be quite serious. This is the list of diseases that can be *directly* transmitted by rodents according to the [CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/rodents/diseases/direct.html):

> - Hantavirus Pulmonary Syndrome
> - Hemorrhagic Fever with Renal Syndrome
> - Lassa Fever
> - Leptospirosis
> - Lymphocytic Chorio-meningitis (LCM)
> - Omsk Hemorrhagic Fever
> - Plague
> - Rat-Bite Fever
> - Salmonellosis
> - South American Arenaviruses (Argentine hemorrhagic fever, Bolivian    hemorrhagic fever, Sabiá-associated hemorrhagic fever, Venezuelan
>     hemorrhagic fever)
> - Tularemia

This is not to say that any given rat or mouse might transmit any of these. Other factors come into play, such as which diseases are endemic to the area and which diseases infect which species. On the link above you can expand each disease to see which rodents can transmit it. Unfortunately, rats and mice are included in most of those diseases.

Comment: Is it a coincidence to see so many different hemorrhagic fevers listed here?

Comment: It only gnawed the skin. There was no bleeding. Can these disease be transmitted through this.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal Yes. Merely being in close proximity to the rodents is sufficient for some diseases. They can be transmitted by urine and feces, and the dust that occurs when feces dry up.

Comment: @CountIblis It _is_ interesting how many hemorrhagic diseases are listed. Maybe that's the rat's revenge for warfarin.